# Concurrent insert in SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, api, concurrency

I have written an api in ASP.NET which uses Entity Framework 6.

Here is the code

```
cr = context.Responses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.RegistrationId ==registrationId);

if (cr == null)
{
    cr = new Responses()
                {
                    Answer = answer,
                    RegistrationId = registrationId,
                    CreationTime = DateTime.Now
                     };
    context.Responses.Add(cr);
}
else
{
    cr.Answer = answer;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

This is my result in database

[image]

But while doing the database inserts, it inserts the same data twice with same creation time which happens often. Why is this so? What is the best way to avoid these duplicate inserts?

Comment: Perhaps the UI (or BL) is sending two add messages running simultaneously? have you considered using a lock(..) statement?

Comment: @LongChalk there is a chance of calling the same simultaneously from UI. How I can block the same? Could you please help me with some sample for lock?

Comment: it's simpler (and uses far less resources) that you put a unique composite index on (Answer , RegistrationId). That's pretty much what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all it should be 
`cr = context.Responses.FirstOrDefault(s => s.RegistrationId == registrationId );`

This is possible this error originates from the UI. suppose you are filling out responses by form, and somebody presses the submit twice, then you would have two lines in the db representing the same response. The correct way to resolve this is to have the form (via javascript and such) generate the guid, and immediately disable the submit button after the click. Another way is to declare in the database that the combinations of result columns are unique, thus no two "same" lines can exist by defintion.

Comment: First thing - My bad. I updated the question
Secondly- I am sure that there is no more code adding to same entity. I have primary key that is a guid. which I have not shown above. I can update the code to have creation time from sql. but still that doesn't solve the issue right?

Comment: It would actually. If you realize that a "Response" is in fact an answer and a registrationId (and not the guidId or the createDatetime, or any other junk you may hold), then you would soon realize these two form a unique composite index. BTW - it's very bad practice to have a guid as a Primary Key. use id identity(1,1) as a PK and in addition have a guidId. That way you gain unprecedented security, without the database fragmentation.